# Django REST reject bad PATCH data

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework

So, I have a patch request that looks like the following to my /user/1 endpoint. Obviously, the "sdfsdf" is not a valid attribute on my User model. When I patch the following, I get a 200 response, but it should throw a 400 or 422 because "sdfsdf" is not a valid field. How do i reject bad patches?

```
{
    "sdfsdf": "sdfsdf"
    "username": "alex"
}
```

My User Serializer lookes like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("first_name", "id", "username")
```

My User View looks like this:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
serializer_class = UserSerializer

def list(self, request, pk=None):
    queryset = User.objects.filter()
    serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
    queryset = User.objects.filter()
    user = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
    serializer = UserSerializer(user)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
    queryset = User.objects.filter()
    user = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)

    if not request.user.pk == user.pk:
        raise PermissionDenied

    serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.data, partial=True)

    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Maybe since you have specifically defined fields to deserialize [fields = ("first_name", "id", "username") ], others are ignored? Remove it and see if exception is thrown.

Comment: no dice, I removed that and it still returns a 200

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `UserSerializer.validate` method to provide object level validation (read more in the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation)).

For example:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("first_name", "id", "username")

    def validate(self, data):
        invalid_keys = set(self.initial_data.keys()) - set(self.fields.keys())
        if invalid_keys:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('invalid keys passed into serializer: {0}'.format(invalid_keys))
        return data
```